# Compare query result are equal

Tags: mysql

| package_id | item_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

How can I check in one query does

```
SELECT item_id 
FROM table 
where package_id =1`
```

is equal to

```
SELECT item_id 
FROM table 
where package_id =3
```

`EXECPT` or `WHERE NOT IN`

won't work if e.g.

```
SELECT EXISTS(
        SELECT item_id 
        FROM table 
        where package_id=2 
        and item_id NOT IN (
                        SELECT item_id 
                        FROM table 
                        where package_id =3
                        )
        )
```

Comment: Compare `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT item_id ORDER BY item_id)`.

Comment: Join the two queries and see if the number of rows in the result is the same as the number of rows returned by one of the queries.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by *Compare query result are equal*. Are the number of rows returned? The values must be equal ? What if one query returned 121 and other 12 , are this equal or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you want to do with this query, but I think you need to review your approach.

Anyway, this query allows you to check if the result of query1 and the query 2 has the same

```
SELECT true AS isSame
FROM   (SELECT item_id,
               Sum(q1) AS q1Sum,
               Sum(q2) AS q2Sum
        FROM   ((SELECT DISTINCT item_id,
                        1 AS q1,
                        0 AS q2
                 FROM   packages
                 WHERE  package_id = 1)
                UNION ALL
                (SELECT item_id,
                        0 AS q1,
                        1 AS q2
                 FROM   packages
                 WHERE  package_id = 2)) allItems) allItemsWithSum
WHERE  q1sum = q2sum
```